# How can I access ARSCNDebugOptions.showBoundingBoxes?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

Working with the Apple ARKit, I am trying to access the `ARSCNDebugOptions.showBoundingBoxes` to lay box over that box and interact with it.

How can I manage this problem? I know that there is the Apple Scanning and detecting of objects but in my opinion the real bounding box debug option is more precise.

Comment: Please add a simple version of your code that you have tried till now. That would be a great starting point for the solvers.

Comment: ´´´self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showBoundingBoxes]´´´there is not much code yet but I would like to access the bounding box values

Comment: I will access width height, position some data like that

Answer (score 1):

> Using **`SCNDebugOption.showBoundingBoxes`** type property you get a **visual representation** of bounding boxes around any debugging objects: geometry, feature points, skeletons, world axes, etc.

```
public static var showBoundingBoxes: SCNDebugOptions { get }
```

> .

```
sceneView.debugOptions = [.showBoundingBoxes]
```

At the moment `ARKit 2.0 API` doesn't allow you to get any info about these bounding boxes i.e. their position and orientation, as well as interact with them.